# Import lines of code

Tags: vba, excel, vbide

Can we read scripts or lines of code to a module in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)? Like we have the include function in [php](/questions/tagged/php).

For example:

We store this in Excel somewhere and call the range as xyz

```
line 1 of code
line 2 of code
line 3 of code
```

Then while running a macro we call this like

```
Sub my_macro()
  xyz
End Sub
```

Basically I want to run a few lines of code repetitively but don't want to create another macro and pass the parameters.

Comment: This can be done utilizing the VBIDE library, but mind if I ask *why* you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks will check it out for future use. I realized that I could achieve my goal by putting it in a loop. But I use this kind of feature a lot in PHP or in any language for that matter. I don't have to worry about creating functions and passing parameters and can just import a set of lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 (VBIDE) library. There's some [great examples at CPearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx). I typically use this to insert snippets of code while I'm developing. I would personally be uncomfortable executing code stored in an excel sheet, but I tested this and it does work.

My worksheet:

```
  A
1 MsgBox "I'm a test."
2 MsgBox "So am I."
```

I set up an empty subroutine that we will then insert into from the excel sheet.

```
Private Sub ProcToModify()

End Sub
```

And the subroutine that will actually insert the code into `ProcToModify`:

```
Sub ModifyProcedure()
        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Dim StartLine As Long
        Dim NumLines As Long
        Dim ProcName As String

        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1") ' specify module to modify
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim cell As Range

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'change this accordingly
        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A2") 'and this

        For Each cell In rng
            ProcName = "ProcToModify"
            With CodeMod
                StartLine = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
                NumLines = .ProcCountLines(ProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
                .InsertLines StartLine + NumLines - 2, cell.Value 'insert each line at the end of the procedure to get them in the correct order.
            End With
        Next cell
End Sub
```

Called at runtime like this:

```
Public Sub main()
    ModifyProcedure
    ProcToModify
End Sub
```

**One Big Gotchya:**
Before running this code, you need to go to Excel>>File>>Options>>Trust Center>>Trust Center Settings>>Macro Settings and check the "Trust access to the VBA project object model".

I would imagine that's because allowing access to the project object is a fairly concerning security risk.

From the cpearson.com site I linked to earlier:

> CAUTION: Many VBA-based computer viruses propagate themselves by
>   creating and/or modifying VBA code. Therefore, many virus scanners may
>   automatically and without warning or confirmation delete modules that
>   reference the VBProject object, causing a permanent and irretrievable
>   loss of code. Consult the documentation for your anti-virus software
>   for details.