# Add a macro in .xlsx with Python or Perl or PHP

Tags: php, python, excel, perl

I would like some help to add a macro in an .xlsx file. I know that's not a good type of file, it should be an .xlsm file, but I have found [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) in Perl that can add a macro to a new .xlsx file.

I want to open an existing .xlsx file (maybe with `Excel::Reader::XLSX`) and add `vbaProject.bin` into this file and save it (maybe as .xlsm). It has a function `"add_vba_project()"` but on `Excel::Writer::XLSX` which can't open existing file.

Has anyone found a solution in Perl or Python or PHP (PHPExcel for example) with or without `vbaProject.bin`?

Comment: Note that it's `perl` not `pearl`

Comment: When doing this natively in VBA, it requires the Visual Basic Extensibility 5.3 library. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23738721/3198973) might be relevant if you need to use that library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you'll find a pure PHP library capable of this, even PHPExcel doesn't support macros; but you can do so using [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) with MS Excel, [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) with Open/Libre Office, or [Ilia's](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel) extension for the commercial [libXL](http://www.libxl.com/) library