# Access 2013 VBA - Setting New Click Event for Controls

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have searched everywhere for this, and it seems like a simple fix, but I can't seem to find the solution. I have several Rectangle controls in my Access 2013 form, and I'm creating an OnClick event that handles them all. I've worked on a few different methods, and I think I found the simplest/cleanest way to do it. I put the controls in a collection and change the OnClick event for each control. Here's my problem: Access opens the form and recognizes that I changed the event for the control, but once I click the control, it throws an error and will not execute the event.

The Error:

> "The expression On Click entered as the event property setting
>   produced the following error: The expression you entered has a
>   function name that Microsoft Access can't find."

The Code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim m_colRectangle As Collection
Dim ctl As Access.CONTROL

Set m_colRectangle = New Collection
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acRectangle Then
        If ctl.Name = "shpTest" Then
            m_colRectangle.Add ctl, ctl.Name

            ctl.OnClick = "=TestClick()" ' <--- Error on this line

        End If
    End If
Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub TestClick()
    MsgBox "Test"
End Sub
```

Alternatively, I tried a simple `shpTest.OnClick = "=TestClick()"` in the Form_Load event, and this produced the same error. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is telling you Access can't find a **function** named *TestClick*.  Your *TestClick* is a subroutine, not a function.

Here is a simpler example, tested in Access 2010 and 2013, which demonstrates that using a function for a control's `.OnClick` property can work ... but you need a **function**.  :-)

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim ctl As Control
    Set ctl = Me.Controls("txtMathExpresson")
    ctl.OnClick = "=TestClick()"
    Set ctl = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function TestClick()
    MsgBox "Test"
End Function
```

Note my Access 2013 test was with a traditional desktop application.  If you're working with an Access 2013 WebApp, I don't know what will happen.

Comment: Wow! It worked! I didn't think to try that. My mind is blown. Thanks for the help! By the way, I am also on the desktop version.

Comment: Ahhhhh I suppose a function ***is*** an expression isn't it?

Comment: I suppose it sometimes just takes a little teamwork to see where it went wrong. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 6):

You don't get to specify which procedure runs in VBA. The procedure that runs will *always* be `ControlName_Click`. The `OnClick` property that you're trying to set only lets you switch between Access Macro and `[Event Procedure]` vba code. It does not work like event delegates do in the .Net platform.

Please see the [OnClick Property documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172963(v=office.11).aspx).

The solution here is to [use the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibilty Library to write snippets of code into the modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736498/import-lines-of-code/23738721#23738721). I'll leave that as as exercise for you.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I thought there may just be something wrong in my formatting. Thanks for your help!