# How to detect focus change to any control?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my form, I need to detect if focus is moved to a new control.

Can I do this for the entire form without having to create event procedures for every control?

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to fire.

```
Private Sub Form_SelectionChange()
    MsgBox Screen.ActiveControl.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use WithEvents. It takes a little and documentation is poor, but it may pay off in the end:

[Using Dynamic External Event Procedures](http://www.vb123.com/Pages/kb/199901_ss_event.aspx)

Comment: Wow, that is a change of approach.  I like it - thanks for the reference.  Now I just have to digest it.

Comment: Can I do this alongside regular click events on the controls?

Comment: This will let me create events for controls that don't already use any events; but how do I do both?

Comment: Just do it. Your class modul with the WithEvents code is referenced when loading and unloading the form. You can reference more than one class - that's the smart part - so you can add just that functionality for a given form you may require. These will work alongside any "normal" code-behind-form you may have or may add.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an event on each control (not exactly what you asked for) but it is pretty clean.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each control As Control In Controls
        AddHandler control.Enter, AddressOf ControlReceivedFocus
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ControlReceivedFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString())
End Sub

End Class
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1159481/2352507

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it.  I could filter out some of the unnecessary controls in the for loop.  Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you can't do this in VBA it seems.  There isn't any `addhandler`, firstly, and you have to use a reference to the parent form in the `for each` statement.  See this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4cae16a1-9c74-4e2b-bd69-24edf24322cd/is-there-a-vba-for-excel-equivalent-to-addhandler-from-vb?forum=isvvba

Comment: That's VB.NET. You need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread has a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26429795/1038866) to add `onClick` events to controls dynamically.  As it turns out, although you can add your own event, you can't add your own event AND have your normal `control_click()` event, too.  It's just that you can set it at runtime via code, and it can be named whatever you want (as long as it is a function).

This sort of answers my question: you CAN add an `onclick` event to every control dynamically without having to create them in the gui.  Here is the syntax which you can put in `form_onload` if you like:

```
with Me.myControl
    Me.myControl.OnEnter = "=SomeFunction()"
end with
```

And here's how to add an `.OnEnter` event to every textbox control (just call the `SetReportControls` method from `form_open`:

```
Private Sub SetReportControls()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        With ctrl
            If TypeOf ctrl Is Access.TextBox Then
                .OnEnter = "=ReportControl(false)"
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Function ReportControl(Cancel As Integer)
    msgbox Screen.ActiveControl.Name
End Function
```

Comment: Don't do this. It's a left-over from Access 1.x where you didn't have the option for code-behind-form modules. It may work, but you loose error handling and - even worse - it is a nightmare to maintain as you cannot easily search or browse what functions ar called where.

Comment: Actually, when you view the controls in the GUI's properties, you can see that the function is attached.  You might be right about the error handling, though.

Comment: Yes, you can see one control at a time. But this is very slow process.