# Excel VBA store functions or subroutines in an array

Tags: vba, excel, vbide

In C/C++, when I have a bunch of functions (pointers), I can store them in an array or a vector and call some of them together in a certain order. Can something similar be done in VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible In VBA. If you attempt that, you will get a compile-error.

Comment: @JLILIAman absolutely possible, just not in a way OP would be accustomed to.

Comment: Ummm, "it depends".  The problem in VBA isn't in storing pointers, it's getting them in the first place, and then using them later.  However, there are various obscure ways to do things *like* this, depending on the context.  So... What are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: @RubberDuck show me an example

Comment: @JLILIAman check my answer below. I have a history with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, but I don't recommend it. VBA isn't really built for it. You've tagged this question with Excel, so I will describe how it is done for that Office Product. The general concept applies to most of the Office Suite, but each different product has a different syntax for the `Application.Run` method.

First, it's important to understand the two different methods of dynamically calling a procedure (sub/function) and when to use each.

## Application.Run

[`Application.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197132.aspx) will either run a subroutine or call a function that is stored in a standard `*.bas` module.

The first parameter is the name of the procedure (passed in as a string). After that, you can pass up to 30 arguments. (If your procedure requires more than that, *refactor for the love of code.*)

There are two other important things to note about `Application.Run`.

1. You cannot use named arguments. Args must be passed by position.
2. Objects passed as arguments are converted to values. This means you could experience unexpected issues if you try to run a procedure that requires objects that have default properties as arguments.

   ```
   Public Sub Test1()
       Application.Run "VBAProject.Module1.SomeFunction"
   End Sub
   ```

### The takeaway:

Use Application.Run when you're working with a standard module.

## VBA.Interaction.CallByName

[`CallByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278760.aspx) executes a method of an object, or sets/gets a property of an object.

It takes in the instance of the object you want to call the method on as an argument, as well as the method name (again as a string).

```
Public Sub Test2()
    Dim anObj As SomeObject
    Dim result As Boolean

    result = CallByName(anObj, "IsValid")
End Sub
```

### The takeaway:

Use `CallByName` when you want to call a method of a class.

## No pointers.

As you can see, neither of these methods use actual pointers (at least not externally). They take in strings that they then use to find the pointer to the procedure that you want to execute. So, you'll need to know the ***exact*** name of the procedure you want to execute. You'll also need to know which method you need to use. `CallByName` having the extra burden of requiring an instance of the object you want to invoke. Either way, you can stores these names as strings inside of an array or collection. (Heck, even a dictionary could make sense.)

So, you can either hard code these as strings, or attempt to extract the appropriate procedure names at runtime. In order to extract the procedure names, you'll need to interface with the VBIDE itself via the [**Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692793.aspx) library. Explaining all of that here would require far too much code and effort, but I can point you to some good resources.

**Articles & SE Questions:**

1. [Chip Pearson's Programming The VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)
2. [Extending the VBA Extensibility Library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52364/extending-the-vba-extensibility-library)
3. [Ugly workaround to get the vbext_ProcKind is breaking encapsulation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63815/ugly-workaround-to-get-the-vbext-prockind-of-a-procedure-is-breaking-encapsulati)
4. [Automagic testing framework for VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63004/automagic-testing-framework-for-vba/63813#63813)
5. [How to get the procedure or function name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945321/how-to-get-the-procedure-or-function-name-at-runtime/23960315#23960315)
6. [Import Lines of Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736498/import-lines-of-code/23738721#23738721)
7. [Meta Programming in VBA: The VBIDE and Why Documentation is Important](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/11/06/meta-programming-in-vba-the-vbide-and-why-documentation-is-important/)

**The code from some of my Qs & As:**

1. [vbeCodeModule](https://github.com/ckuhn203/VBEX/blob/d2d9a5c00c98c4b1df3b956ea060a0539c25f407/src/vbeCodeModule.cls)
2. [vbeProcedure](https://github.com/ckuhn203/VBEX/blob/d2d9a5c00c98c4b1df3b956ea060a0539c25f407/src/vbeProcedure.cls)
3. [vbeProcedures](https://github.com/ckuhn203/VBEX/blob/d2d9a5c00c98c4b1df3b956ea060a0539c25f407/src/vbeProcedures.cls)

Comment: Great answer.  Exactly what I was alluding to in my comment above but was too busy/lazy to expand on.

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung. I obviously have a history with this particular kind of problem. =;)-

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to enumerate and use a switch statement. You can store enumerated types (longs) in an array. E.g.:

```
Enum FType
    func1
    func2
    func3
End Enum

Sub CallEnumFunc(f As FType, arg As String)
    Select Case f
        Case func1: MyFunction1(arg)
        Case func2: MyFunction2(arg)
        Case func3: MyFunction3(arg)
    End Select
End Sub

Dim fArray(1) As FType
fArray(0) = func1
fArray(1) = func2
CallEnumFunc fArray(1), "blah"
```