# Calling subroutine based on a file name or any other criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to call a subroutine based on the file name of the open workbooks.  I have workbook A named "SubModel_OtherAdmin" where I am executing the subroutines and workbook B where I have the VBA logic(subroutines, functions, etc.) stored.  I create a subroutine in workbook B called "Assumptions_OtherAdmin".  Instead of using:

```
Call Assumptions_OtherAdmin
```

I would like to Call that particular subroutine based on the file name in workbook A.  Big picture, Workbook A can be other workbooks such as "SubModel_Marketing" or "SubModel_Revenue", etc.  Each of these will have their own Assumptions subroutine name built and stored in workbook B.

My initial thought was to define a String then use `Call String` but that resulted in an error.  My second thought was to build a table/grid in a tab in workbook B where the subroutines are stored that links the possible file names I will be working with to its respective Assumptions Subroutine name.  For example, in column B row2 I would put the file name "SubModel_OtherAdmin" and in column C row2 I would put "Assumptions_OtherAdmin" and so on.  I'm trying to brainstorm if I should create a function to Call the subroutine by finding the file name in column B and using the name in column C on the same row.  I'm finding myself back to the same error as using `Call String` as mentioned above.  Another avenue I'm looking at is using select Case but I'm stuck in my planning process.  Any thoughts or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA store functions or subroutines in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870454/excel-vba-store-functions-or-subroutines-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Call` keyword is just a deprecated/obsolete way of calling a procedure.

This:

```
Call Assumptions_OtherAdmin
```

Is identical to this:

```
Assumptions_OtherAdmin
```

There's really no reason to use `Call`, it's there only because [much] older versions of the language required it, and it's still there for backward compatibility reasons.

---

You have several options for calling a procedure by name, especially in [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba). How it's going to work depends on where your procedure is located.

---

#### Standard Module

If the code is a `Public` procedure in a standard code module, because Excel's `Application` object has a `Run` method, given a `Workbook` object and a `String` procedure name, you can do this:

```
Public Sub CallMacroByName(ByVal book As Workbook, ByVal procedure As String)
    Dim qualifiedName As String

    If InStr(1, procedure, "'!") = 0 Then
        qualifiedName = "'" & book.FullName & "'!" & procedure
    Else
        qualifiedName = procedure 'assume procedure is qualified already
    End If

    Application.Run qualifiedName

End Sub
```

You would do it like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()

    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = ActiveWorkbook

    CallMacroByName  book, "MyProcedure"

End Sub
```

If all you have is the workbook's full name, you can tweak this code and make it work without a reference to the book in question.

---

#### Class Module

If the procedure you need to call is an object member located in a class module, you'll need to work a little bit harder and pass an instance of the object that exposes the member you want to call. The advantage is that it works whether or not your host application supports `Application.Run`, because you'll be using the `VBA.Interaction.CallByName` standard library function:

```
Public Sub CallObjectMemberByName(ByRef instance As Object, ByVal procedure As String)

    'assumes procedure isn't a property accessor:
    CallByName instance, procedure, VbMethod

End Sub
```

You would do it like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByRef owner As Class1)

    'assumes owner instance is provided by something else
    CallObjectMemberByName owner, "MyProcedure"

End Sub
```

---

If the procedure you want to call is `Private`, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your insight was very helpful.  I was able to tweak it just right for it to work.  The Application.Run is what I wasn't aware of and did not come across it when I was investigating over the internet or overlooked it.  I appreciate it.  I just learned something new.